# Give the three numbers that form a geometric sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Three numbers form a geometric sequence. If 5 is added to the second term, then the resulting numbers will constitute an arithmetic sequence. If 22.5 is added to the third number, these numbers will again form a geometric sequence. Find the original numbers.

Comment: What do you know about geometric sequences? How can you use that information here?

Answer (score 3):

So you are given that the three numbers form a geometric sequence. So write these numbers as $a, ra, r^2a$. ($r$ in this case is the common ratio). Next $a, ra+5, r^2a$ is an arithmetic sequence therefore $ra+5-a=r^2a-(ra+5)$. Simplify to get $a(r-1)^2=10$. Next $a, ra+5, r^2a+22.5$ is a geometric sequence therefore $\frac{r^2a+22.5}{ra+5}=\frac{ra+5}{a}$.

I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Let the terms of the intermediate arithmetic progression be
$$a-b,a,a+b.$$

We can write a condition on the first geometric progression
$$(a-b)(a+b)=(a-5)^2$$
and on the last one
$$(a-b)(a+b+22.5)=a^2.$$

By subtraction,

$$22.5(a-b)=10a-25$$
so that
$$b=\frac{5a+10}9.$$

Plugging in the first equation,

$$\frac{4a-10}9\frac{14a+10}9=(a-5)^2,$$
$$5a^2-142a+425=0.$$

There are two solutions, yielding
$$0.4,-1.6,6.4\to 0.4,3.4,6.4\to 0.4,3.4,28.9$$and
$$10,20,40\to10,25,40\to10,25,62.5.$$